# C - unable to pass int by pointer to nested function call

Tags: c

in Main function, calling a function to loop through a text and check if a column already exists. If not add it into an array of string.

Main:

```
char** departmentList = NULL;

int sizeOfDepartmentList = 0;

departmentList = collectAllDepartments(departmentList, &sizeOfDepartmentList,recordsPtr);
```

Function loop for a text and check for new elements:

```
char** collectAllDepartments(char** departmentList, int *sizeOfDepartmentList, char* records){ 

                        char* copyOfRecords = malloc(strlen(records)+1);
                        strcpy(copyOfRecords,records);

                        char* sav1 = NULL;
                        char* token = strtok_s(copyOfRecords,"\n",&sav1);

                        while(token != NULL){
                            
                            //char *token_orig = _strdup(token);
                            char* sav2 = NULL;
                            char* innerToken = strtok_s(token,",",&sav2);
                            int counter = 1;

                            while(innerToken != NULL){

                                if(counter == 4){

                                    if(!departmentExists(departmentList,*sizeOfDepartmentList,innerToken)){

                                        departmentList = addDepartment(departmentList,&sizeOfDepartmentList,innerToken);
                                        
                                    }
                                        
                                
                                // allDepartments = (char*) realloc(allDepartments,strlen(innerToken) + strlen(allDepartments));

                                // strcat(allDepartments,innerToken);

                                // strcat(allDepartments,",");

                                        
                                }
                                
                                    ++counter;

                                    innerToken = strtok_s(NULL, ",", &sav2);

                            }

                            token = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &sav1);
                            //free(token_orig);

                        }

                        free(copyOfRecords);

                        return departmentList;


 }
```

The function that pushback new elements into the array of string:

```
char** addDepartment(char** deparmentList, int* sizeOfDepartmentList, char* department){

*sizeOfDepartmentList += 1;
deparmentList = realloc(deparmentList, *sizeOfDepartmentList * sizeof(char *));
deparmentList[*sizeOfDepartmentList - 1] = department;
return deparmentList;

 }
```

The int need to be passed by pointer twice in order to be used in the pushback function. But the compiler complaint receiving pointer of pointer instead of pointer:
[image]

Comment: `deparmentList = realloc(deparmentList, *sizeOfDepartmentList * sizeof(char *));` the amount of wrong in a single line is astronomical. Luckily, you can quickly find a problem spot for beginners who try to use `realloc`: the use of `realloc`.

Comment: I thought the realloc here is working fine?

Comment: You're asking me if you think it's working fine? I don't know what you're thinking, you just wrote that..

Comment: If you're trying to ask *why* it's wrong, the answer has to do with the fact that you're not updating the array returned from the function (ie `*deparmentList` instead of `deparmentList`) and you're not checking for `nullptr` results, thus leaking memory on `realloc` failure, which is the best time to leak memory to begin with.

Comment: `addDepartment(departmentList, &sizeOfDepartmentList, innerToken);` The second argument should be `sizeOfDepartmentList`, not `&sizeOfDepartmentList`. It's already a pointer in that context, no need to address it again.

Comment: I am not sure if you mean `*departmentList = addDepartment(departmentList,sizeOfDepartmentList,innerToken); `or `*deparmentList = realloc(deparmentList, *sizeOfDepartmentList * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: I mean the only place in the entire posted code with the *specific* text `addDepartment(departmentList,&sizeOfDepartmentList,innerToken);` . Within `collectAllDepartments` there is *one* call that is *exactly* as I just showed. The second argument to that function call should be pointer-to-int. The argument `sizeOfDepartmentList` is already a pointer to int (it was passed into `collectAllDepartments` as such). Therefore, the `&` is superfluous and is leading to your `int**` where it expects `int*`. That second argument should be `sizeOfDepartmentList`. I don't know how I could say that better.

Comment: I removed the & and it works now, thanks. But what I don't understand is `the fact that you're not updating the array returned from the function (ie *deparmentList instead of deparmentList) `

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as image. Compare https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.